# JDBC, MySQL - DML Error with PreparedStatement executeUpdate

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have two tables. I need to get some column values in a List from second table against col2 and update in the first table on the fly in a loop.

**Code :**

```
int ownerUpdateCount = 0;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try{
        while(featuresIT.hasNext()){
            String feature = (String) featuresIT.next();

            String updateOwnerQuery = "UPDATE `regression_reports` "
                    + "JOIN `feature_testbed_owner_mapping_628` ON (`regression_reports`.Feature='"
                    + feature
                    + "' AND `regression_reports`.Feature = `feature_testbed_owner_mapping_628`.feature_as_on_webpage) "
                    + "SET `regression_reports`.Owner = `feature_testbed_owner_mapping_628`.owner";
            //logger.debug("\n updateOwnerQuery : " + updateOwnerQuery);
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(updateOwnerQuery);
            //ownerUpdateCount += 
            ownerUpdateCount = statement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(feature + " ownerUpdateCount : " + ownerUpdateCount);
        }
        logger.debug("\n ownerUpdateCount : " + ownerUpdateCount);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
           try { if(null!=statement)statement.close();} catch (SQLException e) 
           {e.printStackTrace();}
           try { if(null!=connection)connection.close();} catch (SQLException e) 
           {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

**Error :**

---

> java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:499)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1518)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
>       at com.n7k.regression.RegressionDAO.updateRegReportsDB(RegressionDAO.java:71)
>       at com.n7k.regression.RegressionServlet.doPost(RegressionServlet.java:63)

This error occurs only in the first iteration of the loop. Any suggestion to debug why its happening.

```
String updateFeaturesQuery = "INSERT INTO `regression_reports` "
                    + "(Feature, `Report`, `P`, `F`, `Remarks`) VALUES ('"
                    + feature + "','" + report + "'," + pass + "," + fail
                    + ") " + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Report` = '"
                    + report + "', `P` = " + pass + ", `F`= " + fail
                    + ", `Remarks` = " + remarks + ";";

       connection = dataSource.getConnection();
       statement = connection.prepareStatement(updateFeaturesQuery);

       Line#73 
       featureUpdateCount = statement.executeUpdate(updateFeaturesQuery);
```

**Error :**

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2812)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:228)
>       at com.n7k.regression.RegressionDAO.updateRegReportsDB(RegressionDAO.java:73)

The above execution gives this error. Executing the same query manually doesn't throw me any error.

Comment: **Please** post your **entire** exception.

Comment: Is this the actual code that you're running?  `while(it.hasNext){` looks odd to me.

Comment: **Please** post your **actual** code. `String feature = (String) featuresIT.next(); // <-- Not it?` and `+ colVal //<-- Not feature?` Why aren't you using bind parameters?

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm casting to String. I'm only referencing it for sample code. I'll post the original code.

Comment: Well spotted, @Elliott.  I love the "please help me debug my code that DOESN'T look like this" questions.  Most likely, he/she has just written `executeQuery` instead of `executeUpdate`, but it's anyone's guess.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please have a look at my original code. I'm using executeUpdate. But the first time it in the loop it gives me this DML error.

Comment: @DavidWallace Using a PreparedStatement but shoving constants into the query (which is going to render the Statement cache useless) and even worse [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) vulnerabilities.

Comment: Which statement is **line 71** of `RegressionDAO.java`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, Now it make sense to me. The problem is with a different chunk of code. Without going through completely I made a false assumption. I haven't read the complete error message. I made the changes to executeUpdate in the above code and now it throws a different syntax error.

Comment: Actually calling `executeQuery(<string>)` on a `PreparedStatement` should always throw a `SQLException`. It is a bug that MySQL Connector/J even allows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column `Remarks` is missing entirely here,

```
// No `Remarks` even though you included it in the list. `F`, `Remarks`)
 "," + fail /* + Remarks! */ + ") " + "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Report` = '"
```

Your column `Remarks` is not escaped here,

```
+ ", `Remarks` = '" + remarks + "';";
```

But you **should** use [bind parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) or [String StringEscapeUtils#escapeSql(String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql%28java.lang.String%29) because your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: I just noticed by printing the query statement. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll following your suggestion for the coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

Re the second problem - you are inserting four values into five columns.  You forgot 
"Remarks".

Re the first problem - you haven't shown us the right piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I included the whole code. Can you please refresh and check. I believe it will execute correctly after fixing my first problem. I overlooked the error messages.

Comment: Yes, I read your code before I posted this answer.  Thanks.  You can tell because my answer refers to your latest edit, not the original code that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

you doing some mistake you sql query, like  `;` and you are missing value to get as like 
`Remarks`.

```
  STRING updateFeaturesQuery = 
                 "INSERT INTO `regression_reports` "

                + "(Feature,      `Report`,        `P`,         `F`, `Remarks`) 
                VALUES 
                ('"
                + feature + "','"+report +"',"+ pass +","+ fail+",/*"+ Remarks+"*/ 
                + ") " + 

                "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                `Report` = '"+ report + "',
                 `P` = " + pass + ", 
                `F`= " + fail+ ", 
                `Remarks` = " + remarks + "/*;*/";
```